# Advanced Tab missing from Font Dialogue Box in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

My Excel 2016 is missing the Advanced Tab in the Font Dialogue Box.  I have googled everything I can think of but can't find out how to add that tab on the font dialogue box. I want to use the options on the advanced tab for the character spacing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does not support character spacing in fonts. From what I understand it has never had this capability. The Advanced tab in the Font dialog is found in Word and several other Office products, but not in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use character setting for cells, however you can use it for objects, such as datalabels in charts etc.

If you want to affect objects you can find it where the advanced tab would be in Word, i.e by Ctrl+Shift+F or clicking on the little arrow in the bottom right corner of the Font tab in the Ribbon.

You can also do this in VBA via the Office Object font2.kerning and font2.spacing